# How to (correctly) report timezone using String.format %tz?

Tags: java

If I execute:

```
System.out.println("Formatter: " + String.format("%1$tH:%1$tM:%1$tS %1$tz %1$tZ", now));
System.out.println("SimpleDF : " + new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss Z z").format(now));
```

I expect the result to be the same. If I check the automatically adjust for daylight savings time the values start to vary:

```
without dst (as expected, gmt=9:48):
Formatter: 10:48:16 +0100 GMT+01:00
SimpleDF : 10:48:16 +0100 GMT+01:00
with dst (gmt varies between formatter and sdf ???):
Formatter: 11:47:54 +0100 CEST
SimpleDF : 11:47:54 +0200 CEST
```

Running on win xp, with same results on java 1.6-10/13 and 1.5.0-14, locale en_US. What do you think, a bug?

Perhaps related: https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6286592.

Comment: I think its indead the bug you mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

The correct way is to use the `SimpleDateFormat` (or rather a `DateFormat`) object. String.format is to format strings returned as a result of invocation of the `toString()` method over the object passed. The first line of code can be broken down to something like,

```
String temp = now.toString();
System.out.println("Formatter: " + String.format("%1$tH:%1$tM:%1$tS %1$tz %1$tZ", temp));
```

The temporary string object is formatted using the default locale and settings, and hence, may not guarantee a perfect result (per my experience).

`SimpleDateFormat()` works over the `Date` object and accesses attributes and makes sure of all DST patches.